# Is there anywhere a tutorial of how to publish a book with LaTeX?

Tags: publishing, book-design

I am looking for all the tips and what should be considered specifically for the layout of professionally looking books.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

The [`memoir`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/memoir/) package, more specifically its documentation, is written as an introduction to professional layouts. It contains a lot of examples of different styles of books and how to obtain them. It can be a good start :).

Comment: +1 for the memoir documentation; it's worth a read, even if you don't use the package, for the many sensible things it has to say about layout, etc.

Comment: The book design part of the memoir documentation has been spun off into it's own package: [memdesign](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/memdesign.html)

Comment: Compare to Koma-Script, which one is better?

Comment: I haven't used KOMA-Script much, but judging from what I've seen I prefer `memoir`: more focus on the *why*, better naming conventions, more powerful (on first sight).

Comment: I wouldn't describe one or the other as better --- use Memoir if you need U.S. conventions (and English is your native tongue), Koma-Script if you need European (and your native tongue is the same as one of the developers / documenters who has written docs for it --- last time I looked, the translated into English docs were pretty heard to understand).