# Changing page margins in {pdf-,Xe-}TeX

Tags: xetex, pdftex, margins, tex-core, plain-tex

In TeX, changing the `\hsize` and the `\vsize` changes the main text size and the page size of the dvi output. When I compile a document with pdftex or xetex, the page size remains at A4. How can I change the page margins?

Minimal example:

```
\hsize=5cm \vsize=4cm
\footline{\hfil The page ends here!\hfil\the\pageno}
This document leaves much white space when {\tt pdftex\/}ed or {\tt xetex\/}ed.

\bye
```

Comment: Don't use TeX primitives --- you have to access the pdf-specific information/options (see the manuals for pdftex and xetex). I provide an example of how to do this using XeLaTeX in this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19497/how-do-you-setup-a-tex-document-to-self-publish-a-book-online/130843#130843

Comment: Actually changing hsize/vsize does _not_ change the page size in dvi either, unlike pdf, dvi has no concept of the page size. \hsize \vsize just affects the size of the text block in tex and pdftex. pdftex has a `\pdfpagewidth` primitive that has no analogue in classic tex.

Comment: @WillAdams that's not tex primitives, it's plain TeX, so a latex/memoir solution isn't applicable

Comment: @DavidCarlisle that means that TeX can't, e.g., center the text on the true page margins? If I want, say, 2 times more space on the left margin than on the right one, I have to compute manually the `\hoffset` and `\voffset` needed?

Comment: classic TeX has no idea of the page, it just sets the text block at a position offset from the top left corner. Classically the dvi driver needed to be told the paper size. essentially pdftex is its own driver so needs the page size.

Answer (score 3):

Solution for {Lua-,pdf-,Xe-}TeX

```
\hsize=2in \vsize=3in
\pdfpagewidth=4in
\pdfpageheight=5in
\footline{\hfil The page ends here!\hfil\the\pageno}
This document is by far better! Notice that \TeX{} starts every page
one inch away from the upper and left margin.
This example doesn't compile with {\tt tex} anymore.

\bye
```

Comment: There are still `\voffset` and `\hoffset` to keep into account, because the origin is always at 1in from the top and left page margins; `pdftex` and LuaTeX have `\pdfhorigin` and `\pdfvorigin`, but XeTeX doesn't know them (while it has `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`).